# Cars' wear resistance, quietness and water drainage dependence on thread pattern on tires?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction, applied-physics, contact-mechanics

Why can tires with fine thread patterns increase cars' wear resistance, quietness and water drainage? What is the logic behind?

The following is the tire ad I saw:

> [image]
>
> Nowadays, under the premise of pursuing comfort, most of Sedan / Saloon's tires have begun to adopt the design of fine tread patterns, that is, a very small gap is drawn between the tire blocks by laser or other manufacturing processes.  The central Z-shaped tread pattern of Yokohama L752R adopts the design of the fine tread pattern that has been popular among sedan / saloon tires, which can increase its wear resistance and also increase the quietness.  The side is also designed with a fine tread pattern to increase the car's drainage and wear resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how this works. When a rubber tire rotates and comes into contact with the pavement, the round rubber tire gets deformed (pressed flat against the flat pavement). 
Since the tire wants to remain round, this causes the tire surface to "scrub" against the pavement which grinds away at the tire surface, wearing off the rubber and turning it into dust. And when the tire's rolling action takes the tire surface out of contact with the pavement, the deformed part of the tire snaps back into its round shape and this "snap" radiates sound into the tire, the wheel, the suspension and into the body of the car where you hear it.

By putting lots of thin open spaces between little patches of tire surface, all those individual parts of the tire can more easily conform to the pavement without deformation: the "scrubbing" action is lessened, and wear is reduced. And the tire surface can "unscrub" without snapping back, reducing the noise output.